# Choosing the right data from a table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

Lets say I have this table name "Stuff"

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ VAL ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ A   ║
║  2 ║ B   ║
║  3 ║ C   ║
║  4 ║ C   ║
║  5 ║ C   ║
║  6 ║ D   ║
║  7 ║ B   ║
║  8 ║ E   ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

I would like a query which can give me an output of where in the numbers the letters are repeating. Feel free to use any column name for the table.

Basically I want something that says "C" is reapeating on number 3, 4, and 5. "B" is repeating on number 2, and 7.

On my work I have thousand of rows. The example I gave you is very granular. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: What is your expected output? For example if you sort by val theb all the records with the same val will be grouped together so it will be easy to see what IDs each one of them relates to. I'm guessing this is not what you want. So what do you?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT Val, Id =
    STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + CAST( Id as varchar(20))
           FROM Stuff b 
           WHERE b.Val = a.Val 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Stuff a
GROUP BY Val;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bee51/8)

Output:

```
╔═════╦════════════╗
║ VAL ║     ID     ║
╠═════╬════════════╣
║ A   ║  1         ║
║ B   ║  2 , 7     ║
║ C   ║  3 , 4 , 5 ║
║ D   ║  6         ║
║ E   ║  8         ║
╚═════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Yep, this, and all the rest of techniques from here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: @zespri - Nice link. Thanks.

Comment: @hims056 - In your query DISTINCT with GROUP BY is unnecessary.

Comment: @Devart - Yeah. Corrected. Didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: +1 - for the good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Id INT, Val CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @temp (Id, Val)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C'),
    (4, 'C'),(5, 'C'),(6, 'D'),
    (7, 'B'),(8, 'E')

SELECT
      Val
    , RepeatValues = STUFF((
          SELECT ', ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10))
          FROM @temp a
          WHERE a.Val = b.Val
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM @temp b
GROUP BY Val
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this...

```
SELECT
      name
    , STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
          FROM [stuff] a
          WHERE a.name = b.name
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS RepeatIds
FROM [stuff] b
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: +1 - for the good answer.

Comment: @Devart thank's!!!!!! and many thanks for making my answer look gud....thanks fr your edit too...

Comment: Also preferably use `VARCHAR(<max_length_of_your_datatype>)` instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)`. And you're welcome @AmitSingh :).

Comment: @Devart i m not sure of length of given data type...so thats y i taken as max...does it make an impact??

Comment: It's not critical, but in your case allocated more memory than you really need.